Microsoft question regarding IIf statement or a better solution
I am working on a report that needs international addresses that are correct to the country's standard to where the mail is going.
Some countries want the postal code before the City, others don't and some have regions/states, while others dont.
I have this expression:
=IIf(Eval([country] In ("Italy","Czech Republic","Argentina","Austria","Belgium","China")),([zip] & " " & [city]),([city] & ", " & [region] & " " & [zip]))
I might have another 5-10 countries to put in.. Is there a better way of handling this in expression builder with like a lookup or something? I did not know if there is a limit to how long a expression can be in Access.
Thanks for any input.
It is working right now, but looking for a better solution.

Consider creating a function. This function accepts Country, City, Region, and Zip as parameters. Within the function use a SELECT CASE statement on Country and return the appropriate formatted string for each case.
In a MODULE add:
Public Function CityZip(Optional strCountry As String="",Optional strCity As String="",Optional strZip As String="",Optional strRegion As String="") As String
    
    Select Case strCountry
        Case "Italy", "Czech Republic", "Argentina", "Austria", "Belgium", "China"
            CityZip = strZip & " " & strCity
        Case Else
            CityZip = strCity & " " & strRegion & " " & strZip
    End Select
    
End Function

You can then use the function as an expression instead of IIf:
=CityZip([country],[city],[zip],[region])


Where about in MS Access do you do that?

Database tools - Visual basic - Insert - Module

Thank you!, how do I call that from the MS Access report?

Added Optional keyword so function behaves as expected even if a null value is passed in.

When I add this code into MS Access 365 the Public function is red,
https://snipboard.io/kEI8P9.jpg

@ChuckS, you missed _ symbol at the end of the lines

I apologize ahead of time.. have never done this before: I get this parameter value popup when I run: https://snipboard.io/fdHiAR.jpg
This is the code in the field: =CityZip([country],[city],[zip],[region])

And here is the VB module code, which is now good: https://snipboard.io/IHc4lx.jpg

What is the name of your module? maybe try =Module1.CityZip([country],[city],[zip],[region])

So the case function for this line in the function is returning this on the report: #Type!   But the non "Italy.." line is working properly. As seen here: https://snipboard.io/89Jh5E.jpg

I have updated the Function to include the "" default values. Do all 4 parameters [country],[city],[zip],[region] have the same data type?

Yes, they do .. all text fields https://snipboard.io/6PyJsu.jpg

Here is a screenshot of data in one that is giving the #Type Error https://snipboard.io/2uQnTz.jpg

This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19710398/type-error-on-report-calculated-field

Thank you again for getting me this far, much appreciated!

Consider using a lookup table that flags zip/country order preference. You can build such a table from existing data (ideally using country ID):
SELECT DISTINCT country, 0 AS zip_first
INTO country_preferences
FROM myTable

Then adjust default by UPDATE queries or in table UI:
UPDATE country_preferences
SET zip_first = 1 
WHERE country IN (
  'Italy',
  'Czech Republic',
  'Argentina',
  'Austria',
  'Belgium',
  'China'
);

Finally, join the new lookup table to original table for much simpler, efficient, and scalable IIF expression:
SELECT
    t.[country],
    IIF(
       c.[zip_first] = 1, 
       t.[zip] & ' ' & t.[country],
       t.[city] & ', ' & t.[region] & ' ' & t.[zip]
    ) AS location
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN country_preferences c
  ON t.[country] = c.[country]


thanks for that, I had already try to travel down that path, but the latest iteration of MS Access and ODBC MYSQL connectors fails on building queries. It was stated on M$ website.. as when you try to open a linked table it fails, yet you can build reports... I wish I could do it this way! https://snipboard.io/Aahpnt.jpg  https://snipboard.io/Vmn5Hq.jpg

Very important to have mentioned and tagged your backend! But sounds like you need to build the table in the actual backend, here being MySQL. Then, link that table back in Access. MySQL uses CREATE TABLE AS and not INTO clause. Either run such queries in pass-through queries from Access or do operations in a MySQL instance (i.e., mysqlsh, workbench).
